# Vue.js: converting a new Vue().$mount() to an export for server side rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Vue app that I'm trying to convert to server-side rendering.

Currently, the app attaches to the root HTML element through this file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppLayout from './theme/Layout.vue';
import router from '../router';
import store from './vuex/index';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    router,
    ...AppLayout,
    store
}).$mount('#app');
```

I would like to export this root file for my **server-entry.js** file.

What's the most efficient way to do this? Should I refactor the main.js file? Should I create a separate file, the only purpose of which would be to pull in all the imports listed above and export an app, then import it and mount it  in **main.js**? What would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have right now, which works:

app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppLayout from './theme/Layout.vue';
import router from '../router';
import store from './vuex/index';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const app = new Vue ({
    router,
    ...AppLayout,
    store
});

export {app, router, store};
```

main.js:

```
import {app} from './app';

app.$mount('#app');
```